# How to choose the right TTL value for Web-push?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, web-push

How to choose the right value for the TTL? We need a push messsage delivered reliably, not being dropped, but at the same time we would like it delivered faster, because it is used to initiate live calls. I understand that `0` is not an option for us, since it has a good chance to be dropped? But then should it be `60*60` (an hour) or `60` (a minute) or what is the right way of thinking here?

Answer (score 1):

You must remember that the value of [TTL paramater](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/web-push-protocol#ttl_header) must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds, and it corresponds to the maximum period of time of push message to live on the push service before it's delivered.

> If you set a TTL of **zero**, the push service will attempt to deliver the
>   message immediately, but if the device can't be reached, your message
>   will be immediately dropped from the push service queue.

You can also consider the following [best practice of using TTL](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/about-ttl-best-practices/):

> - The higher the TTL, the less frequently caching name servers need to query authoritative name servers.
> - A higher TTL reduces the perceived latency of a site and decreases the dependency on the authoritative name servers.
> - The lower the TTL, the sooner the cached record expires. This allows queries for the records to occur more frequently.